# Weird NIntegrate behavior

Tags: numerical-integration

If I evaluate the following, Mathematica does not give any error and returns a `0`.

```
SeedRandom[123];
pdf=SmoothKernelDistribution[RandomReal[{0,1},100],MaxExtraBandwidths->0];
g[x_]:=undefined[x];
NIntegrate[PDF[pdf,z] g[z],{z,0,1},Method->{Automatic,"SymbolicProcessing"->0},AccuracyGoal->15]
```

If instead I remove either the method option to the accuracy goal option, Mathematica returns, as it should, an error and repeats the input expression. Does anybody know if this is a bug or an expected behavior? It was quite difficult to discover this silent bug.

Comment: Please note the tag wiki for the [tag:bugs] tag: "This tag is reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug. Please do not use this tag for new questions. Please use the standard bugs header instead of version tags in conjunction with this tag."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `NIntegrate::inumr` error ["is generated when none of the values of the integrand for the sampling points in a region...is a number"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/NIntegrate/inumr.html.en).  Your integrand evaluates to `0.` for (at least) one point in the initial integration region `{0., 1.}`.  Since you set `"SymbolicProcessing"->0`, `NIntegrate` seems to assume your function has only a measure-zero set of singular points and bases its estimate ignoring the nonnumeric results.  The integral and and error estimate are both `0.`, which would fail the precision goal if `AccuracyGoal` is set to `Infinity` but passes if `AccuracyGoal` is set to any finite positive number.  If you allow `"SymbolicProcessing"`, then `NIntegrate[]` would divide the interval at the boundaries of the `Piecewise` function `pdf`.  This creates a region in which "none of the values of the integrand for the sampling points in a region...is a number", and you get the error.

```
NIntegrate[PDF[pdf, z] g[z], {z, 0, 1}, 
 Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, AccuracyGoal -> 15,
  IntegrationMonitor :> (Print[Map[{#1@"Boundaries", #1@"Integral", #1@"Error"} &, #1]] &), 
 EvaluationMonitor :> Print["z: ", z]]
(*
  z: 0.00795732

  {{{{0,1}},0.,0.}}

  0.
*)
```

Only one point is used apparently to estimate the integral and the error.  Yikes.

Comment: thanks! quite bad luck to have these three conditions at the same time (a function that gives 0, no symbolic processing and finite accuracy goal)

Comment: @Valerio You're welcome. I think you should file a bug report with WRI. I came short of calling it a bug, but I think the behavior is undesirable and can probably be avoided. `NIntegrate[]` actually evaluates your function at 11 points, only one of which is a valid numeric result (the one reported by `EvaluationMonitor`). You'd think that would at least deserve a warning message.

Comment: I just reported it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[123];
```

It would be more informative to call the distribution something like `dist` rather than `pdf`

```
dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100], 
   MaxExtraBandwidths -> 0];
```

Verifying that the total probability is one

```
Integrate[PDF[dist, x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(*  1.  *)
```

The `Mean` is

```
mu = Mean[dist]

(*  0.49436  *)
```

Alternatively,

```
mu == Expectation[x, x \[Distributed] dist]

(*  True  *)
```

Similarly,

```
var = Variance[dist]

(*  0.0678187  *)

var == Expectation[(x - mu)^2, x \[Distributed] dist]

(*  True  *)
```

You cannot `Integrate` or `NIntegrate` an undefined function such as `g` or `undefined`

```
Expectation[g[x], x \[Distributed] dist]
```

[image]

```
Integrate[g[z] PDF[dist, z], {z, 0, 1}]
```

[image]